# jQuery dynamic content loaded via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hey all i am trying to close a div that displays when the page loads. However, doing this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery('#moreDetailsTable').slideUp("fast", function () {});
});
```

Doesnt seem to close it when the page loads since its dynamicly being populated via PHP code using **ajax**.

The php that ajax calls looks like this:

```
echo '<div id="moreDetailsTable" class="widefat fixed comments">
    Testing this out<br />
    Testing this out<br />
    Testing this out<br />
    Testing this out<br />
    Testing this out<br />
</div>
   ect ect.....
```

I know the code work because i just do this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#moreDetailsTable', function() {
    jQuery('#moreDetailsTable').slideUp("fast", function () {
        console.log('done');
    });
});
```

And it slides up once i **click on it**.

How can i called the **.slideUp** since its dynamically populated and not on the page to start with?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: @Jordan make that an answer so i can give you credit, please.

Comment: Can you show your ajax code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [jQuery.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) event handler. This will do what you want.

Example:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
   jQuery('#moreDetailsTable').slideUp("fast", function () {});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again, Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function when the ajax returns. After load the content. Something like:

```
$('.ajaxLoading').show();
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'url',
    dataType: "json"}).done
    (function(response){
        alert(response.message);
        $('.ajaxLoading').hide();
        //window.location = "/dash_board";
            $('#moreDetailsTable').slideUp("fast", function () {});
    }).fail(function(response,textStatus){
        alert('Something goes wrong. Please try again.');
        $('.ajaxLoading').hide();
        //alert(textStatus);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay to my problem, Jose.